# How to ignore return value different then 0 when I have set -e?

Tags: bash

I often add `set -e` in my bash scripts. However this time I have to call a command that returns some meaningless number instead of 0 on success. How can I tell bash to ignore the return value of this command only.

Changing the command, or changing it's code to conform to the standard is not an option.

Comment: Good on you for using `-e` (`errexit`)! I would also suggest using `-u` (`nounset`). See; https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`true` always returns a zero exit code. So you can do

```
command-with-meaningless-return-value || true
```

Comment: Or `! command` if incomprehensibly it returns 0 for failure and >= 1 to indicate e.g. the number of successful operations (trust me, there are such horrible aberrations).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use the value of `$?` later, you can do:

```
# A test funtion to demonstrate different exit status values
$ exit_with(){ return $1; }

$ exit_with 0

$ echo $?
0

$ exit_with 4

$ echo $?
4

$ exit_with 4 || true

$ echo $?
0

# capture the exit status rather than clobber it
$ exit_with 4 || exit_status=$?

$ echo $?
0

$ echo $exit_status
4
```

In this case use `$exit_status` instead of `$?`. I've not found a way to do something like `?=$?` or `declare ?=$?`