# execute next command if the previous command fails or successful in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
npm audit > log.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ $? -eq 0 ];then
 command ABC
fi
```

I know that npm audit is failing. As per the if condition, command ABC should get executed. But it is not. Any pointers.

Comment: `[ $? -ne 0 ] || [ $? -eq 0 ]` will always be true.

Comment: `npm audit >log.txt; command ABC` -- if you want to _unconditionally_ proceed, that's what `;` (or a newline) is for.

Comment: If it's not doing that, that implies you have `set -e` enabled. [`set -e` should not ever be used by anyone](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- the _only_ way to write reliable error-handling in bash is to do it by hand, for the reasons described in the link.

Comment: ...however, you _can_ work around it, as with `npm audit >log.txt ||:; command ABC`.

Comment: Anyhow -- if the above _is_ your problem, that makes the question duplicative of [temporarily disable `set -e` / `set -o errexit` in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899561/temporarily-disable-set-e-set-o-errexit-in-bash), or [How to ignore return value other than 0 when I have `set -e`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609701/how-to-ignore-return-value-different-then-0-when-i-have-set-e).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I tried with ; but command ABC is not called and process exited before it. If I am trying ||, then the command ABC will only be called if npm audit fails.

Comment: See `||:;`, as shown in my above comment -- that's important. It's not just `||`

Comment: and yes, your shell clearly has `errexit` behavior turned on. Read the FAQ linked above, and unless you're very sure you want it on, turn it off. (A lot of CI systems enable errexit by default, but it's a horribly bad decision, and proof that they're being built by people who don't know shell well).